# Unable to generate Android Digital Assets Links file for debug

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a debug keystore using Android Studio's Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK, and when selecting the debug signing config, I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w1sB.png).

Any ideas?

I have tried selecting the keystore file directly as well, and I expected to have the assets links file to be generated. The release signing config works.

Comment: your keystore file is incorrect or need to new keystore file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Android Studio, I created the file by hand, using `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore` to get the sha